# .ics export from Google calendar has wrong time

Tags: php, import, icalendar

Using PHP,mysql, i am trying to export/import calendar data from/to Google calendar.
The importing (to Google) works fine. I can export data from my mysql table and create an ics file then import it into Google Calendar, using a specific timezone.

The problem is when i am exporting the data... Google changes the timezone for every event. I'll give an example.

When i am importing the data to Google Calender, a typical event looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20
DTSTAMP:20160328T222128
DTSTART:20160328T033000
DTEND:20160328T043000
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:My description here
SUMMARY:Event number 3
END:VEVENT
```

The StartTime is **033000** and EndTime is **043000**. Everything is fine, i see an event starting at 3:30am and ending at 4:30am.

When i am exporting my calendar from Google this event looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160328T003000Z
DTEND:20160328T013000Z
DTSTAMP:20160328T194501Z
UID:20
CREATED:20160328T224357Z
DESCRIPTION:My description here
LAST-MODIFIED:20160328T194410Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Event number 3
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

StartTime **003000** EndTime **013000**

Both .ics files have **X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Athens**

Why on earth is Google sending me back Zulu time, instead of what i am seeing in the calendar ?
I dont want to handle timezones. This means if a person from the Usa uploads an .ics file to the custom calendar i am making, it will insert wrong times in the database. Is it possible, Google Calendar to export exactly the hours a person sees in his calendar?

If i cant avoid this, what is the easiest way to convert this Z time into the proper time ? (the time that person sees in Google Calendar)

Thanks!

Comment: You have to post your code if you want help fixing it.

Comment: What code ? From Google ? Like i said....GOOGLE exports .ics files with Zulu time not the time on the calendar you exported...Is there a way i can force export the time on the calendar instead? And if not, then what is they best way to do this with the .ics that google provides.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. You have your question tagged "php", so show the PHP script that's having trouble doing the import or export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that, since you are able to insert the date/times into a database, you are able to parse the format of `DTSTART`. If not, I recommend taking a look at [sabre/vobject](http://sabre.io/vobject/) for a full-on iCalendar parser.

So after parsing `DTSTART`, make sure you parse this into a php `DateTime` object. This object makes it really easy to convert to different timezones:

```
$dt = new \DateTime($input);
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Athens'));
```

After that, your `$dt` contains your start time, converted to your timezone.

Here's an example with vobject:

```
$cal = Sabre\VObject\Reader::read($iCalendarData);

// DTSTART property
$dtstart = $cal->VEVENT->DTSTART;

// Turn into DateTime object
$dateTime = $dtstart->getDateTime();

// Convert to your timezone
$newDateTime = $dateTime->setTimeZone('Europe/Athens');
```

Disclaimer: I'm the main author for vobject.

Comment: Awesome thanks Evert...Thats what i thought..I have to convert google's DTSTART and DTEND values to my timezone right ? I thought i was going crazy. I couldnt find any example out there that was doing this...They were all just importing the values to the database, without any timezone conversion first. 
Thanks for the code and class, i'll have a look at it tomorrow :)

Comment: Well, one thing to keep in mind is that the .ics file that you are _importing_ to google also does not have its timezone information correctly set. If your imported file had it's timezone information correctly set, the export would probably also be in the correct timezone.

Comment: wow....i thought my export was correct before i import it into Google. Do you mind taking a look here and tell me if it looks wrong to you ? The hours are exactly the way i have them in my DB. http://pastebin.com/eqYXhngR

Comment: @user1033882: yes it's still wrong. Try exporting an event from google that *does* have it's timezone info explicitly set. Pay special attention to `TZID` appearing on `DTSTART` and `VTIMEZONE` components.